# How to split a column value to multiple columns based on delimiter in Snowflake

Tags: sql, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need to split column value into multiple columns based on delimiter,
Also need to create columns dynamically based on no. of delimiters, delimiter could be comma or so. Thanks,

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: As Gordon says, it's hard to know how to answer this question with an input an desired output. Here I wrote the answer to a similar, more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65257962/132438

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off working with an array in this case.  You haven't specified whether each record will have the same number of delimiters, so dynamically creating columns for tables will take some scripting.  If they are, you could potentially use a `SPLIT`, `LATERAL FLATTEN`, and `PIVOT`, but the pivot needs static column names, so you'll likely need a stored procedure to deal with that.

To answer your first question, you can use `SPLIT` and/or `SPLIT_PART` to split the column into values.  The `SPLIT` function creates an array for you, while the `SPLIT_PART` function creates the array, but outputs a single value from the array.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html