# How can I split a string into character in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, arrays, string, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to split a string like "abc" into individual records, like "a", "b", "c".

This should be easy in Snowflake: `SPLIT(str, delimiter)`

But if the delimiter is null, or an empty string I get the full `str`, and not characters as I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update: SQL UDF

```sql
create or replace function split_string_to_char(a string)
returns array
as $$
split(regexp_replace(a, '.', ',\\0', 2), ',')
$$
;
select split_string_to_char('hello');
```

---

I found this problem while working on [Advent of Code 2020](https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/1336059863080730624).

Instead of just splitting a string a working solution is to add commas between all the characters, and then split that on the commas:

```sql
select split(regexp_replace('abc', '.', ',\\0', 2), ',')
```

[image]

If you want to create a table out of it:

```sql
select *
from table(split_to_table(regexp_replace('abc', '.', ',\\0', 2), ',')) y
```

[image]

As seen on https://github.com/fhoffa/AdventOfCodeSQL/blob/main/2020/6.sql

Comment: Filed internally as SNOW-242435

Answer (score 3):

You can use [regexp_extract_all()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all) function in Snowflake to extract every char into an array.

See the following code as an example:

```
regexp_extract_all('abc','.{1}')
```

Comment: Correct! This was introduced in 2022 - thanks for the note https://community.snowflake.com/articles/Knowledge/6-14-Release-Notes-April-27-May-2-2022

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Felipe's approach, you could also use a JavaScript UDF:

```
create function TO_CHAR_ARRAY(STR string)
returns array
language javascript
as
$$
    return STR.split('');
$$;

select to_char_array('hello world');
```