# How to iterate through substrings that contain a combination of characters

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-api

I want to make a Tableau report from this SQL to show apppointment availaility throughought various locations at a facility. For example, between 8:00am and 3:00pm, we have appointments available at the following times.  (I'll have to join anoter table to grab availaibility)

I'm trying to pull out every value that contains an 'O1' sequence from this field. Every two-character combination represents one fifteen minute block. If there's no appointment at that time, it shows '00'. An '01' singifies that an appointment sits in that desingated time slot. I don't know how to show an '01' block/substring as a booked appointment

```
<SQL> 

    SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 1, 2) AS "12:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 3, 2) AS "12:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 5, 2) AS "12:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 7, 2) AS "12:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 9, 2) AS "1:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 11, 2) AS "1:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 13, 2) AS "1:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 15, 2) AS "1:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 17, 2) AS "2:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 19, 2) AS "2:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 21, 2) AS "2:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 23, 2) AS "2:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 25, 2) AS "3:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 27, 2) AS "3:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 29, 2) AS "3:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 31, 2) AS "3:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 33, 2) AS "4:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 35, 2) AS "4:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 37, 2) AS "4:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 39, 2) AS "4:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 41, 2) AS "5:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 43, 2) AS "5:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 45, 2) AS "5:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 47, 2) AS "5:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 49, 2) AS "6:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 51, 2) AS "6:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 53, 2) AS "6:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 55, 2) AS "6:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 57, 2) AS "7:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 59, 2) AS "7:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 61, 2) AS "7:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 63, 2) AS "7:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 65, 2) AS "8:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 67, 2) AS "8:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 69, 2) AS "8:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 71, 2) AS "8:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 73, 2) AS "9:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 75, 2) AS "9:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 77, 2) AS "9:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 79, 2) AS "9:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 81, 2) AS "10:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 83, 2) AS "10:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 85, 2) AS "10:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 87, 2) AS "10:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 89, 2) AS "11:00AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 91, 2) AS "11:15AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 93, 2) AS "11:30AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 95, 2) AS "11:45AM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 97, 2) AS "12:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 99, 2) AS "12:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 101, 2) AS "12:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 103, 2) AS "12:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 105, 2) AS "1:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 107, 2) AS "1:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 109, 2) AS "1:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 111, 2) AS "1:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 113, 2) AS "2:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 115, 2) AS "2:15M",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 117, 2) AS "2:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 119, 2) AS "2:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 121, 2) AS "3:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 123, 2) AS "3:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 125, 2) AS "3:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 127, 2) AS "3:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 129, 2) AS "4:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 131, 2) AS "4:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 133, 2) AS "4:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 135, 2) AS "4:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 137, 2) AS "5:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 139, 2) AS "5:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 141, 2) AS "5:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 143, 2) AS "5:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 145, 2) AS "6:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 147, 2) AS "6:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 149, 2) AS "6:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 151, 2) AS "6:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 153, 2) AS "7:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 155, 2) AS "7:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 157, 2) AS "7:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 159, 2) AS "7:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 161, 2) AS "8:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 163, 2) AS "8:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 165, 2) AS "8:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 167, 2) AS "8:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 169, 2) AS "9:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 171, 2) AS "9:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 173, 2) AS "9:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 175, 2) AS "9:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 177, 2) AS "10:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 179, 2) AS "10:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 181, 2) AS "10:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 183, 2) AS "10:45PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 185, 2) AS "11:00PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 187, 2) AS "11:15PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 189, 2) AS "11:30PM",
    SUBSTRING(N.AOBLOC, 191, 2) AS "11:45PM",

   
 FROM PROD_ODS_DB.WELIB.VMPAPOPN AS N
 WHERE N.AOTLCD = 'DALTX'
AND N.AODATE = '2023-02-16'
```

I considered har-coding case statments for all of this but I don't know how to set it up. I don't know if I can temporarily store this in an array or table and then loop through the values? I wouldn't know how to go about that.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Here's an interesting solution which is similar... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65257962/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-character-in-snowflake  You might create a table out of the result and then the index numbers will directly correspond to dates/times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regexp_extract_all()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all) function in Snowflake to extract every 2 chars into an array.

See the following code as an example:

```
SELECT
    regexp_extract_all(N.AOBLOC,'.{2}') as appointments_array
FROM PROD_ODS_DB.WELIB.VMPAPOPN AS N
WHERE N.AOTLCD = 'DALTX'
AND N.AODATE = '2023-02-16'
```

Comment: This is perfect! But, how would I label appointment times?

Comment: Hi @Martin, your query currently builds those appointment time as column names, if that is still the desired case, then column names can not be dynamically generated within SQL itself, you can do it  in a sql wrapper programming language, such as Python.

Comment: Ahh, I see. How do I pull out values from this array?

Comment: Hi @Martin, it is a array, you can pull the data out by index.

Comment: Now that I've read some more, I've realized I need to turn the columns into rows since you can only join based on row values. What should I do instead?

Comment: Hi @Martin, could you clarify a bit more on how do you want to achieve by saying "turn the columns into rows" in this business context?

Comment: So, once the tables get brought over to snowflake, I'll have to join what's scheduled (this table)  with what's actually available at every location. Some places accept appointments from 7:30am - 3:30 etc. All will vary by day.

Comment: The end goal is to filter by location and date to show what's available and what's been booked.